# Unable to pass locale to an email template on symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm beginner to Symfony. I created a base website with login based on this explanation : https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#form-login, and a User entity / registration form to allow users register.

After that, I added {_locale} on my pathes to enable translations.

I added the SymfonyCasts\Bundle\ResetPassword\SymfonyCastsResetPasswordBundle bundle to add a request password page, and generated it with bin/console make:reset-password.

I added {_locale} on the base route in top of my reset-password controller :

```
#[Route('/{_locale}/reset-password')]
class ResetPasswordController extends AbstractController {
    ...
}
```

To have a fully working translated website.

I configured mailer, enabled messenger (with php bin/console messenger:consume async) and tried the reset password process without success.

Each time I try to send mail the following error is triggered :

> Error: "Handling "Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage" failed: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some mandatory parameters are missing ("_locale") to generate a URL for route "app_reset_password"."

In the email template, the problematic code is :

```
<a href="{{ url('app_reset_password', {token: resetToken.token}) }}">{{ url('app_reset_password', {token: resetToken.token}) }}</a>
```

I tried many tests but none work...

Tried to pass locale by the controller as context in the mail

```
$email = (new TemplatedEmail())
    ->from(new Address('mymail@gmail.com', 'Addresses tracker'))
    ->to($user->getEmail())
    ->subject('Your password reset request')
    ->htmlTemplate('reset_password/email.html.twig')
    ->context([
        'resetToken' => $resetToken,
        '_locale' => $translator->getLocale(),
    ]
);
```

Tried to use the app.request.locale in twig :

```
<a href="{{ url('app_reset_password', {'_locale': 'en', token: resetToken.token}) }}">{{ url('app_reset_password', {'_locale': 'en', token: resetToken.token}) }}</a>
```

Or even set directly the value :

```
<a href="{{ url('app_reset_password', {'_locale': app.request.locale, token: resetToken.token}) }}">{{ url('app_reset_password', {'_locale': app.request.locale, token: resetToken.token}) }}</a>
```

But unfortunately the error persists.

If anyone can point me how to resolve this problem that would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: You don't need to add locale to every route, check the docs https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/translation/locale.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @nacholibre for your suggestion.

I finally found a solution to do the job. It seems I had to first clear caches and restart server to take the modifications in account... It was my first problem. After the link builded correctly, the second problem was only link was translated, not the text.

Here is the call to send the mail :

```
$context = [
    'resetToken' => $resetToken,
    '_locale' => $translator->getLocale(),
];
$email = (new TemplatedEmail())
    ->from(new Address('titi2027@gmail.com', 'Addresses tracker'))
    ->to($user->getEmail())
    ->subject($translator->trans('resetpassword.mail.subject'))
    ->htmlTemplate('reset_password/email.html.twig')
    ->context($context);

$mailer->send($email);
```

Notice that the _locale is set in context, and the subject is translated with the $translator passed as argument on the method.

The trick is in the mail template...

I can use the following syntax :

```
{% trans from 'messages' into _locale %}string.to.translate{% endtrans %}
```

to specify the locale to use for translation. After using this on each text, all seems to be ok.

Here the final template :

```
<h1>{% trans from 'messages' into _locale %}resetpassword.mail.hi{% endtrans %}</h1>

<p>{% trans from 'messages' into _locale %}resetpassword.mail.info{% endtrans %}</p>

<a href="{{ url('app_reset_password', {_locale: _locale, token: resetToken.token}) }}">{{ url('app_reset_password', {_locale: _locale, token: resetToken.token}) }}</a>

<p>{% trans from 'messages' into _locale %}resetpassword.mail.expiration{% endtrans %} : {{ resetToken.expirationMessageKey|trans(resetToken.expirationMessageData, 'ResetPasswordBundle', _locale) }}.</p>

<p>{% trans from 'messages' into _locale %}resetpassword.mail.cheers{% endtrans %}</p>
```

Hope it can help